# Trying to return a string, without the first and last character, but code is breaking in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am currently learning TS and I am having an issue.  The following function is supposed to return a string without the first and last character. Can somebody help out?  I have provided the code and explanation of my thought process. Hopefully, you can clarify this for me. Thank you.

I wanted to initialize an empty string, that way you can pass in any string full of characters. I wanted to return that string, but with the missing first and last character, by using the slice method. Then, I created a new variable `const answer` to store my answer so then I can call it up using console.log.

```
export function removeChar(str: string): string {
 var str = ""
 return str.slice(1,-1)
}


const answer = removeChar("Hello, how are you?")
console.log(answer)
```

Comment: The `var str = ""` shouldn't be there, it is shadowing the `str` parameter passed as the function argument, causing a reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [dafault value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) set in the function arguments declaration:

```js
export function removeChar(str: string = ""): string {
 return str.slice(1,-1)
}


const answer = removeChar("Hello, how are you?")
console.log(answer)
```